# Questions about CUDA memory

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu

I am quite new to CUDA programming and there are some stuff about the memory model that are quite unclear to me. Like, how does it work? For example if I have a simple kernel

```
__global__ void kernel(const int* a, int* b){ 
    some computation where different threads in different blocks might      
    write at the same index of b
}
```

So I imagine `a` will be in the so-called constant memory. But what about `b`? Since different threads in different blocks will write in it, how will it work? I read somewhere that it was guaranteed that in the case of concurrent writes in global memory by different threads in the same block at least one would be written, but there's no guarantee about the others. Do I need to worry about that, ie for example have every thread in a block write in shared memory and once they are all done, have one write it all to the global memory? Or is CUDA taking care of it for me?

Comment: Searched and didn't find, but I apologize if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

> So I imagine `a` will be in the so-called constant memory.

Yes, `a` *the pointer* will be in constant memory, but not because it is marked `const` (this is completely orthogonal). `b` *the pointer*  is also in constant memory. *All* kernel arguments are passed in constant memory (except in CC 1.x). The memory pointed-to by `a` and `b` could, in theory, be anything (device global memory, host pinned memory, anything addressable by UVA, I believe). Where it resides is chosen by you, the user.

> I read somewhere that it was guaranteed that in the case of concurrent writes in global memory by different threads in the same block at least one would be written, but there's no guarantee about the others.

Assuming your code looks like this:

```
b[0] = 10; // Executed by all threads
```

Then yes, that's a (benign) race condition, because all threads write the same value to the same location. The result of the write is defined, however the number of writes is unspecified and so is the thread that does the "final" write. The only guarantee is that at least one write happens. In practice, I believe one write per warp is issued, which is a waste of bandwidth if your blocks contain more than one warp (which they should).

On the other hand, if your code looks like this:

```
b[0] = threadIdx.x;
```

This is plain undefined behavior.

> Do I need to worry about that, ie for example have every thread in a block write in shared memory and once they are all done, have one write it all to the global memory?

Yes, that's how it's usually done.

Comment: Ok thanks, so this raises further questions to me. So I should write something like this: `__synctreads(); if(threadId.x == 0) for(i=...) b[i] = s[i]`, assuming I have a shared array s where each thread writes what it has to. And what about shared memory ? Are the writes atomic ? Or am I supposed to take of it myself as well ? Thanks for your answers, and sorry if my questions are basic, I'm new to CUDA.

Comment: Well it's a follow-up and it's mostly the same subject, is it really needed to create a second thread ?